# Batch file for loop doesn't like parenthesis

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a simple batch file that will execute a block of commands for each folder in a directory. Here is my code:

```
for /D %%x in ("C:"*) do echo "Folder found!">>test.txt
```

That works. The trouble is, when I add parentheses to execute several commands in each folder, the operation crashes. It doesn't run the loop:

```
for /D %%x in ("C:"*) do(
   echo "Folder found!">>test.txt
)
```

Causes a crash.

I can't find anything on google. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try `do (` (note the space). I assume you're not *actually* working with DOS - it has much more limited batch capabilities. Oh, and what does `>>` do? Shouldn't that be just `>`? Also, make sure to use quotes for the file paths (otherwise spaces are going to ruin your day) and note that you can't use a closing parenthesis inside the loop body - if you need something more complex, you'll have to use `goto`.

Comment: `>>` appends to a file. He said what he is working with -- batch files.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the tips; I'm pretty new to batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simply the missing space after `do` change to `do (`

Also the pattern `"C:"*` is the current directory prepended with `"C:"`, for `C:\` itself;

```
for /D %%x in ("C:\*") do (
    echo "Folder found!" 
)
```